# Xcode 7.3 Visual Debugger - Outline Around Views Missing?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode7.3

In Xcode 7.3 the visual debugger no longer shows the light grey outline around each view, making it hard to see the different views. This is what I see (it is **missing** the grey outline):

[image]

This is what it used to show in Xcode 7.2 (it **has** the grey outline arounds views):
[image]

Any ideas why, something I need to turn back on, a bug maybe? I have tried toggling the options along the bottom of the visual debugger.

I am showing `Wireframes and Contents` and toggling constraints seem to be broken too!

Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at another Xcode and the lines were there, so assuming this is a bug, I reinstalled Xcode and it fixed itself.

Comment: Reinstalled Xcode yesterday, but still no wireframes.  If anybody has another solution I'd be grateful!

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re-installing too, but the wireframes are not there. Is this the default for 7.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles